# How to remove the fonts in CKEditor RTE of TYPO3 v10?

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, rte, typo3-10.x

I need to remove some of the fonts listed in the CKEditor RTE.
[image]

Is this possible? How to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, fonts are being listed from system-specific and listed in the CKeditor. But, you can customize this.

I am not sure about `YAML` configuration for the TYPO3, But, you can use Javascript to archive this. You can override Javascript for an override font option.

**Javasrcript**

```
CKEDITOR.config.font_names = 'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;' +
    'Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;' +
    'Georgia/Georgia, serif;' +
    'Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;' +
    'Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
    'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
    'Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
    'Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif';
```

**YAML (Not tested!)**

According to the configuration formate, below `yaml` configuration should work. But, I have not tested ;)

```
editor:
  config:

    font_names: "Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"
```

Here is the official document: [font_names](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-font_names)

Code example: [Example](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/a786d6f43c17ef90c13b1cf001dbd00204a622b1/plugins/font/plugin.js#L382-L398)

Hope this works!